# How do I loop through an array and print out the positive values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My current code loops through the array, creates a new one and returns all the values that are above 0, but how do I make it more efficient so that it just prints them out without making a new array and such?

```
    let nums = [190, -4, -8, 2130, 87, 123, -5];
function printPositives(array) {
  let pos = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > 0) {
      pos.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return pos;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean more efficient less code or faster?

Comment: You're just making one new array. JavaScript is pretty good at making objects.

Comment: `let nums = [190, -4, -8, 2130, 87, 123, -5];`
`nums.filter(num => num>0);`

Answer (score 3):

A simple one could do like this:

```js
let nums = [190, -4, -8, 2130, 87, 123, -5];

nums.map(element => {

if (element > 0) console.log(element); 

})
```

Comment: If the returned new array from `.map()` isn't going to be used, you might as well use `.forEach()`.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is iterate an array and print values that meet your criteria with no need to keep those results separate from the starting values, use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)  which will not mutate the array or create a new array.

```js
let nums = [190, -4, -8, 2130, 87, 123, -5];

function printPositives(array) {
  array.forEach(function(item){
    if(item > -1){
        console.log(item);
    }
  });
}

printPositives(nums);
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a new array in this example won't harm performance,
if you want your code to avoid using a new array and mutate the original array you could simply splice every number that is less than `0`

```js
let nums = [190, -4, -8, 2130, 87, 123, -5];
function printPositives(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < 0) {
      array.splice(i,1)
      i--
    }
  }
  return array
}
console.log(printPositives(nums))
```

However if your propose is less code you could use `filter` instead

```js
let nums = [190, -4, -8, 2130, 87, 123, -5];
result=nums.filter(n=>n>0)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let nums = [190, -4, -8, 2130, 87, 123, -5];

nums.filter(num => num > 0).forEach(num => console.log(num));
```